# Real-life example of negative probability amplitudes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

Scott Aaronson has written an (of course) excellent article on quantum mechanics and about the importance of negative (and complex) probability amplitudes in understanding quantum effects and quantum computing: http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html

One part that really fascinates me is his example of how applying a seemingly randomizing operation twice to a qubit can "derandomize" it again because the negative amplitudes allow events to cancel out (about mid-way into the article, search for "So given a qubit, we can transform it..." to find the place, it is really short).

Is there a real life example of this? For instance, a polarity filter (as seems to be so often used in quantum experiments) that can be applied to photons and that has the same matrix as he uses in his example (and hence has the same effect on the probability amplitudes). I imagine then you could have an experiment where you had an initial stream of photons in, say, horizontal polarization who would go through the first filter, producing a stream of photons with 50% in horizontal and 50% in vertial polarization. Passing that stream into another instance of the filter would then produce a stream of photons in vertial polarization (with the randomness having disappeared).

My question is, is such a filter realizable/available? Or is there another way to realize the demonstation of the negative amplitudes?

Comment: Negative probability sound strange. In the beginning of the lecture, he says that one should think about amplitudes. That is fine, the amplitude $\psi \in \mathbb C$ whereas the probability density $\rho = |\psi|^2 \in \mathbb R^+_0$. That just cannot be negative. But quantum mechanics works with amplitudes, sure.

Comment: @Martin: It is negative _probability amplitudes_. My understanding is that until you measure the system, the weighting of the various outcomes in the superposition involves complex numbers and mathematically act as probabilities with the twist that they are negative. It is only when you measure the system those numbers get "converted" (or at least you can think of it that way) into ordinary probabilities (through absolute value and squaring as you write) and the outcome is then determined based on those probabilities.

Comment: The overlap between states as well as the time evolution of the system works with those complex numbers. You are right, as long as you do not measure, there is unitary evolution which is all about complex amplitudes. When you measure, you take the absolute square. All that is correct, I just find it troublesome to have the words “complex” and “probability” next to each other. The amplitudes are of course closely connected to probability, but it is not directly the same.

Comment: Yes me too - but I thought it was standard terminology to call it probability amplitudes and not specific to Aaronsons presentation?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can add a single arbitrary phase to the state of any quantum system, so for simple enough system the amplitude can always be made positive. Or negative. Or purely imaginary. So, in one sense *every* quantum system is an example or both. But the importance arises in system with cross-terms where you can only force on of them to have the character you want.